# How to set volume of VLCMediaPlayer on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, libvlc

I'm using `MobileVLCKit` in form of `MobileVLCKit-prod version 2.7.9` from CocoaPods.

I am initializing `VLCMediaPlayer` this way

```
VLCMediaPlyer *player;
....
player=[[VLCMediaPlayer alloc] init];
player.delegate=self;
VLCMedia * media;
media=[VLCMedia mediaWithURL:@"UrlOfRemoteAudiFile"]
```

I don't setup player.drawable because I only need audio and remote file doesn't contain video stream anyway.

Audio file plays correctly. Pause/resume works.
but I cannot change sound volume: player.audio.volume returns 0, attempts to assign player.audio.volume value in interval 0..200 are ignored with no change in volume.

I currently test on **iOS9**.

Only solution I found so far which works is changing system volume.

Answer (score 0):

only way I find to do that (partially based on code from ttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/33168497/ios-9-how-to-change-volume-programmatically-without-showing-system-sound-bar-po ) is just change system volume. 
code like this.

```
- (void) fakeSystemVolumeSetup:(float)newValue {
    MPVolumeView* volumeView = [[MPVolumeView alloc] init];

    // Get the Volume Slider
    UISlider* volumeViewSlider = nil;

    for (UIView *view in [volumeView subviews]){
        if ([view.class.description isEqualToString:@"MPVolumeSlider"]){
            volumeViewSlider = (UISlider*)view;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Fake the volume setting
    [volumeViewSlider setValue:newValue animated:YES];
    [volumeViewSlider sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

It works and it turned out that having system indicators active is even better for this project.